# Inheritance of pure virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Parent {};

int main() {
    Derived d1;
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt over here is that, print function in the parent class is a private member function, then how does it get inherited in the derived class?

Comment: Virtual methods can be overriden, even if they are private. Its just is as it is.

Comment: That capability in C++ is used as part of the [non-virtual interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) pattern.